# Delete latest data from mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 4.0. By mistakenly, I insert 100 BTC blocks transaction data in the wrong collection. Now I want to remove only that data which is inserted recently. I am not getting that how much data is inserted. I just know that data is inserted today. Can somebody give me some suggestion how can I remove this data?

Comment: Do you have point in time backup setup?

Comment: What sort of deployment do you have (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster) and what sort of values are you using for the `_id` in this collection? Default [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) values include a leading timestamp component that could help you identify newer records. The [replication oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog) would provide a more precise history of document inserts (assuming it hasn't rolled over yet). If either of those aren't options, perhaps you can construct a query based on BTC transaction dates.